# exe file generated by pyinstaller does not work when downloading from google drive

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I made some program by Python 3.7 and generated an exe file using pyinstaller.
The exe file worked fine, but the problem occurred when I uploaded it on google drive to distribute to other users.

When I download the program from google drive, the exe file does not work.
To be exact, it actually runs only on background. Since I made GUI for this program, it must show window GUI but it doesn't.

Even I have same problem when I run the program which is downloaded from google drive.

What is the problem? and what should I do?

Comment: Are you downloading it from Google Drive and testing it on the original computer where you first created it?

Answer (score 0):

You said the file downloaded from Google Drive doesn't work as the one you directly generated. I have a little trouble believing that Google drive modifies your file, you can nevertheless do the test by comparing the checksum. Does the checksum of your file change when you upload it to google drive? If this is the case try to go through another platform.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself.
The problem is that uploading exe file itself.
When I made a zip file for exe and uploaded it, the exe file worked fine.